# How to define OneSignal Segments through application

Tags: ionic-framework, onesignal

I need to define a custom segments through application using OneSignal. I want to know if this is possible.

For example, when I initialize the application I need a way to send the custom segments to OneSignal API like:

createCustomSegment({key:"cars", value:"Cars"});

If the segment doesn't exists it creates and subscribe the user. If exists, just subscribe.

If this is not possible, theres a way I can add the user to an segment through application?

Answer (score 2):

OneSignal Segments can only be created on the dashboard, you can setup them up to look for specific tag keys and values. Then use [window.plugins.OneSignal.sendTags](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ionic-api-reference#sendTags) to tag the device from your app.

Instead of creating Segments you can use the 'tags' field on the OneSignal [create notification](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/notifications-create-notification) REST API call.